# Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel (Shape Mismatch Issue)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel.

You can access my code on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/code/dyimahansah/nlp-competition-dansah

Once I attempt to train the model using the following line of code:

```
history = classifier_model.fit(x=Train_ds,
                                validation_data=Val_ds,
                                epochs=EPOCHS)
```

I receive the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 1
----> 1 history = classifier_model.fit(x=Train_ds,
      2                                 validation_data=Val_ds,
      3                                 epochs=EPOCHS)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /tmp/__autograph_generated_filev3ngj1gm.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

File /tmp/__autograph_generated_file__2um3fl.py:74, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__call(self, inputs, training)
     72     result = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(smart_cond).smart_cond, (ag__.ld(training), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=True), fscope)), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=False), fscope))), None, fscope)
     73 result = ag__.Undefined('result')
---> 74 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.not_(ag__.ld(self)._has_training_argument), if_body_3, else_body_3, get_state_3, set_state_3, ('result', 'training'), 1)
     76 def get_state_6():
     77     return (result,)

File /tmp/__autograph_generated_file__2um3fl.py:72, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__call.<locals>.else_body_3()
     70     training = False
     71 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(self).trainable, if_body_2, else_body_2, get_state_2, set_state_2, ('training',), 1)
---> 72 result = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(smart_cond).smart_cond, (ag__.ld(training), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=True), fscope)), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=False), fscope))), None, fscope)

File /tmp/__autograph_generated_file__2um3fl.py:72, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__call.<locals>.else_body_3.<locals>.<lambda>()
     70     training = False
     71 ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(self).trainable, if_body_2, else_body_2, get_state_2, set_state_2, ('training',), 1)
---> 72 result = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(smart_cond).smart_cond, (ag__.ld(training), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=True), fscope)), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=False), fscope))), None, fscope)

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1023, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_file__2um3fl.py", line 74, in tf__call
        ag__.if_stmt(ag__.not_(ag__.ld(self)._has_training_argument), if_body_3, else_body_3, get_state_3, set_state_3, ('result', 'training'), 1)
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_file__2um3fl.py", line 72, in else_body_3
        result = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(smart_cond).smart_cond, (ag__.ld(training), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=True), fscope)), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=False), fscope))), None, fscope)
    File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_file__2um3fl.py", line 72, in <lambda>
        result = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(smart_cond).smart_cond, (ag__.ld(training), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=True), fscope)), ag__.autograph_artifact(lambda : ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(f), (), dict(training=False), fscope))), None, fscope)

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'preprocessing' (type KerasLayer).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py", line 237, in call  *
            result = smart_cond.smart_cond(training,
    
        ValueError: Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel. Got:
          Positional arguments (3 total):
            * <tf.Tensor 'inputs:0' shape=(None, 2) dtype=string>
            * False
            * None
          Keyword arguments: {}
        
         Expected these arguments to match one of the following 4 option(s):
        
        Option 1:
          Positional arguments (3 total):
            * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
            * False
            * None
          Keyword arguments: {}
        
        Option 2:
          Positional arguments (3 total):
            * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
            * True
            * None
          Keyword arguments: {}
        
        Option 3:
          Positional arguments (3 total):
            * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='inputs')
            * False
            * None
          Keyword arguments: {}
        
        Option 4:
          Positional arguments (3 total):
            * TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='inputs')
            * True
            * None
          Keyword arguments: {}
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'preprocessing' (type KerasLayer):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 2), dtype=string)
      • training=True
```

I know that there is a shape mismatch but I am not clear on how to solve it. I believe the error is on reference to the following lines of code:

```
type def build_classifier_model():
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='sentences')
  preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, input_shape=[2], name='preprocessing')
  encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
  encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
  outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
  net = outputs['pooled_output']
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None, name='classifier')(net)
  return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)here
```

How I can resolve this?